# cuPrintf does not print anything even if the compilation is ok

Tags: c++, cuda

Here is my includes:

```
#include "cuPrintf.cu"
#include "cuPrintf.cuh"
```

My kernel:

```
__global__ void testKernel()
{
  cuPrintf("Test");
}
```

and my main:

```
int main( int argc, char** argv) 
{   
    dim3 threads(1,1);
    dim3 blocks(1, 1);
    testKernel<<<blocks, threads>>>();
}
```

Can someone explain to me why the `cuPrintf` does not print anything, the compilation is ok and I am using Cuda 5.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a cc 2.0 or higher device, it's easier just to use `printf` directly from the kernel.  You can do this as long as your compile command specifies `-arch=sm_20` or similar, for whatever is your actual device.

If you really want to use `cuPrintf` then [study the relevant sample code](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#simpleprintf).  You are missing a couple function calls in your `main` routine that are needed for `cuPrintf` to work correctly.

Finally, whenever you are printing from a kernel, you should make sure to have some synchronization function before your program exits.  If you don't have anything else after your kernel, then the following will do:

```
cudaDeviceSynchronize();
```

in your `main` routine, after the last kernel call.

If you modify your `main` routine like this:

```
int main( int argc, char** argv) 
{   
    dim3 threads(1,1);
    dim3 blocks(1, 1);
    cudaPrintfInit();
    testKernel<<<blocks, threads>>>();
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    cudaPrintfDisplay(stdout,true);
    cudaPrintfEnd();
}
```

I believe it will work.

Comment: I tried the `-arch=sm_20` but it didn't work, what is this argument? can it be a different number?

Comment: Are you doing proper cuda error checking as you were previously advised?  You can read about arguments to the nvcc compiler [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html#nvcc-command-options).  The `-arch=sm_20` switch tells the compiler to generate code for a cc2.0 device.